# Как получить return из функции в c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть вот такая функция:

```
public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
    {
        //here we're going to get a list of all running processes on
        //the computer
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
            {
                //if the process is found to be running then we
                //return a true
                return true;
            }
        }
        //otherwise we return a false
        return false;
    }
```

и в итоге я хочу получить либо True, либо False передав ей аргумент в static void Main(). Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: а что именно идет не так?

Comment: Я хочу использовать эту функцию в static void Main() и не знаю как получить return.

Comment: добавсь слово static после public

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Напиши ответом отмечу как решение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в том, что из статического метода нельзя вызвать динамический пока не создашь инстанс класса, что бы уже у него уже вызвать метод.

В твоем случае лучше сделать сам метод статическим. То есть добавь слово `static` после `public` и проблема решена.